Nuxt 3 HMR Module not reloading changes
I have nuxt 3 project and installed couple of packages .
the hmr was working fine .. it just stopped suddenly no clue why .
there's no errors in the console . the cmd shows the files are being updated .
but the browser isnt reloading the changes
i did try ssr:false and this vite config :
  vite: {
    server: {
      watch: {
        usePolling: true,
      },
      hmr: {
        protocol: 'ws',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 24679, 
      },
    },
  },
 

i have to refresh the page every time i make a change .
any clue why this suddenly stopped ? i updated the nuxt 3 to latest version as well

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Ok i figured it out for anyone having this issue
the issue was naming the components
I had components named like this :
MyComponentOne
I changed it to :
Mycomponentone
it worked

is there an explanation?
